# How to integrate Audio Capture task in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How do I record audio in Windows Phone 8?
Which method is useful?

see my code:

```
private Microphone _microphone;
private byte[] _buffer;
private TimeSpan _duration;

_microphone = Microphone.Default;
_microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
_duration = _microphone.BufferDuration;
_buffer = new byte[_microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(_microphone.BufferDuration)];
_microphone.BufferReady += _microphone_BufferReady;
_microphone.Start();

void _microphone_BufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _microphone.GetData(_buffer);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Have you done any googling? You questions is very broad?

Comment: @Christos yes,I edited my question. see my code

Comment: @SonerGönül first of all sorry brother..see my edited code, how do I launch audio capture?thnx